# how to get intance of CI in codeigniter's Exception library

Tags: codeigniter, class-library

i just want to run $CI=&get_instance in Exception library of codeigniter. but its not running there. while the other Classes in Library folder are able to create such instance, but the Exception is not. the reason i want to do this is , i want to use this instance to load a view page in show_404(){} method.
thanks in advance

Comment: I'm having this same issue. I'd like to extend the exception class to allow me to treat errors as normal pages, giving them at least a view to avoid out-of-place looking error messages and having to maintain a ton of error pages in every language with a hacky solution to make them work.

Answer (score 0):

Are you thinking about extending CI's Exceptions library?  if so, you may want to do

```
<?php
class MY_Exceptions extends CI_Exceptions {
    // your code here
}
```

then you don't need to do $CI &= get_instance();

Comment: Ahh, but you see, we're already doing that, and it works fine. The problem is that (I think) we both want access to controllers so we can load views for our errors, instead of having to maintain a bazillion unique error pages (localization) with a hacky solution to make them work.